# Arduino I2C Register Read

Tags: arduino-mega

I am trying to read a specific register from a device. In this case I am trying to read the value stored in register 0X1F from slave device 0x08. On the scope I see writes for

```
ADDRESS_SLAVE(Wire.beginTransmission), ADDRESS_TESTCOMP0 (Wire.write)
```

and

```
ADDRESS_TESTCOMP0 (Wire.requestFrom(ADDRESS_TESTCOMP0,8))
```

but I don't see the register values reading out.  Here is my code:

```
#include <Wire.h>

int ADDRESS_SLAVE = 0X08;
int ADDRESS_TESTCOMP0 = 0X1F;


void setup() 
{
 Wire.setClock(3400000); 
 Wire.begin();
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
   Wire.beginTransmission(byte(ADDRESS_SLAVE));  
   Wire.write(byte(ADDRESS_TESTCOMP0));  
   Wire.endTransmission(byte(ADDRESS_TESTCOMP0)); 

   Wire.requestFrom(ADDRESS_TESTCOMP0,8);    
   char read = Wire.read();
   Serial.println(read);

   delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: please format your code  as `code` ..... select the code text and click `{}` ..... or just indent each line by 4 more spaces

Comment: maybe the arduino is "talking" too fast

Comment: Remove the Wire.setClock. The arduino mega 2560 can not do 3.4MHz. Only 100 kHz and perhaps 400 kHz with short wires. The Wire.endTransmission does not take data as a parameter, only a parameter for a stop condition. The Wire.requestFrom takes the slave address as a parameter, not the register address. The second parameter of the Wire.requestFrom is the number of bytes that you want, since you want just 1 byte, make that 1 and not 8. Which device is it? I hope not a device that runs at 3.3v. Start here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/wire and read the reference pages of the functions.

Comment: Wire.begin sets default clock. the setClock line is not applied

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback. Code is still not accomplishing what I need it to and maybe I am going about it all wrong. Here is what I am trying to do:

Comment: I corrected set clock to 100K, eliminated the parameter in end transmission, corrected the request from parameter and set it to 1 byte....I am still not reading the register I am looking for. This is a 5 volt device. I've read the reference section on the wire library on the Arduino website exhaustively, which is why I am here now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

errors corrected

```
#include <Wire.h>

byte ADDRESS_SLAVE = 0X08; 
byte REGISTER_XY = 0X1F;
byte READ_LENGTH = 8;

void setup() 
{
 Wire.begin();
 Wire.setClock(400000); // set I2C 'full-speed'
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
   Wire.beginTransmission(ADDRESS_SLAVE);  
   Wire.write(REGISTER_XY);  // set register for read
   Wire.endTransmission(false); // false to not release the line

   Wire.requestFrom(ADDRESS_SLAVE,READ_LENGTH); // request bytes from register XY
   byte buff[READ_LENGTH];    
   Wire.readBytes(buff, READ_LENGTH);
   for (int i = 0; i < READ_LENGTH; i++) {
     Serial.println(buff[i], HEX);
   }
   Serial.println();
   delay(1000);
}
```

if you read only one register of the device, you can setup the device in `setup()` and in `loop()` only read the data from the register:

```
#include <Wire.h>

byte ADDRESS_SLAVE = 0X08; 
byte REGISTER_XY = 0X1F;
byte READ_LENGTH = 8;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Wire.begin();
  Wire.setClock(400000); // set I2C 'full-speed'

  Wire.beginTransmission(ADDRESS_SLAVE);  
  Wire.write(REGISTER_XY);  // set register for read
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

void loop() {
   Wire.requestFrom(ADDRESS_SLAVE,READ_LENGTH); 
   byte buff[READ_LENGTH];    
   Wire.readBytes(buff, READ_LENGTH);
   for (int i = 0; i < READ_LENGTH; i++) {
     Serial.println(buff[i], HEX);
   }
   Serial.println();
   delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: we don't know if the register address is 8-bit or 16-bit. Perhaps the slave is a microcontroller and needs a delay. The Wire.read does not take parameters, it reads a single byte. You were thinking about Wire.readBytes? We don't know how long the wires are and we don't know what the slave device is or how it behaves.

Comment: @Juraj Wow...thank you very much Juraj! That works! It seems like I was pretty far off the mark with what I was trying to do. Do you know of an available reference I can use for these types of problems i.e. text/book?